# How to remove Create react app sample in production

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, production-environment

I have a domain which is successfully deployed in production server.
But whenever I open it one `Install app: Create React app sample` is showing in address bar.

Is there any way to remove this.
What should i change in my code?
Any suggestion here?

//Client package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-less": "^3.3.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

//manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change manifest.json file, you might find it in public folder which is created by create-react-app.

manifest.json file is used by serviceWorker to let user install your webapp as a app, you can skip short_name property, but you should provide a proper name. but skipping both won't casue any problem in functionality of the app, in this case browser will use default name (i.e. untitled) for your app.

In my suggestion, you should provide both `short_name` and `name` property.

In there

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample", // you need to change this
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: Hi Hussain, Thank you for your response. should I remove it  or what. I will update my question with current manifest json.

Comment: i have updated the answer, basically it's the name of the app, replace default name with your app name

Comment: Is there any sideeffect if I dont provide any name or shortname at all ?

Comment: because I don't want to come something with indtall app or so.

Comment: Manifest.json file is used by serviceWorker to let user install your webapp as a app,you can skip short_name property, but you should provide a proper name.  but skiipping both won't casue any problem in functionality of the app . https://w3c.github.io/manifest/.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to temporarily hide that icon, you can comment out the line that looks like `<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />` in `your-project-root/public/index.html`, don’t need to remove or modify `manifest.json`.